# Кастомная авторизация Spring REST API

Tags: java, spring

Как грамотно и удобно организовать аутентификацию в Spring REST Api через JWT? Сессию не хочу использовать, потому что это REST и JWT. Проверка токена должна проходить при каждом запросе, который требует аутентификации. Токен хранится или в куки или передается в хедерах(это не столь важно).

Вопрос в том, как можно сделать аутентификацию, максимально простой в использовании, что бы написать, допустим, фильтр, и забыть про это. Что бы внутри каждого метода где нужна аутентификация, не дергать что то типо getUser(). Хочется просто написать и забыть, но что бы этот юзер уже был внутри метода и с ним можно было работать.

До этого писать Api на SparkJava, там все было очень просто. Вместо стандартного Route, там где надо было, возвращал самописный SecuredRoute, который в свою очередь имплементился от стандартного Route, и переопределял его стандартный метод handle, в котором была написана логика проверки авторизации, и если юзер авторизован, то дальше передавался handleSecured, в параметрах которого уже был сам юзер.

Код для наглядности, который был на spark

```
public interface SecuredRoute extends Route {

    @Override
    default Object handle(Request request, Response response) {
        // Логика проверки...
        if (юзер не прошел провеку) {
            response.removeCookie("/", "accessToken");
            return new ErrorResponse(response).errorResponseUnauthenticated();
        }
        return handleSecured(request, response, user);
    }

    Object handleSecured(Request request, Response response, User user);
}
```

Можно ли что-либо подобное сделать на Spring?

Мне кажется что в идеале было бы создать какую то свою аннотацию, которая ставилась бы перед методом, в котором нужна авторизация, и как то инжектила этого юзера в метод

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, после продолжительных поисков, в интернете было найдено пара статей, на основе которых удалось сделать то что хотелось. Получилось добавить немного "магии" в Spring.

Я не хотел использовать Spring Security, потому что мне показалось не очень удобных прятать все урлы, доступ к которым есть только у авторизованных пользователей, за общий, например "/sicret/**" поэтому пришлось написать небольшой кусок этого Security самому.

Просто оставлю это здесь, вдруг у кого то будет такая же потребность.

Аутентификация происходит "за кулисами" с помощью аннотации, в которой достается jwt из куки или из хедеров. Происходит парсинг этого jwt, достается юзер и "прокидывается" внутрь метода, в котором нужен авторизованный пользователь. В случае если все ок, то есть токен был распаршен и юзер получен, то он "прокидывается" в метод, если же что-то пошло не так, то выбрасываем свое исключение, которое потом будем обрабатывать в глобальном обработчике эксепшенов, и возвращать JSON ответ вместо стандартного респонса в виде html страницы.

Теперь сам код

Аннотация. Никакие параметры в нее передаваться не будут

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface AuthUser {
}
```

"Обработчик" аннотации. Оставлю только основной код, так как логика обработки токена и получения юзера здесь не столь важна

```
public class AuthUserHandlerMethodArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {    
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        return methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(AuthUser.class) != null && methodParameter.getParameterType().equals(User.class);
    }
    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer modelAndViewContainer, NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest, WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory) throws Exception {
        if (this.supportsParameter(methodParameter)) {
            // Получаем токен из куки или хедера, парсим его
            if (с юзером все ок) {
                return user;
            } else {
                throw new FailedAuthenticatedException();
            }
        }
        return WebArgumentResolver.UNRESOLVED;
    }
}
```

Регистрация обработчика

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        resolvers.add(new AuthUserHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
    }
}
```

Контроллер

```
@RequestMapping(value = EndPoints.AUTH_CHECK_AUTHORIZED_WITH_COOKIE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Response getUserInfo(@AuthUser User user) {
// здесь уже можно работать с юзером как с аутентифицированным
}
```

Глобальный обработчик эксепшенов

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalHandlerExceptionControllerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
    public Response databaseError(Exception exception, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (exception instanceof FailedAuthenticatedException) {
            // сюда попадаем в том случае, если ловим наш эксепшен, то есть, когда юзер не аутентифицирован. И возвращаем наш response в виде json в качестве ошибки
           return new ErrorResponse(ErrorResponse.Error.AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }
        // в остальных случаях возвращаем сообщение об ошибке
        return new ErrorResponse(ErrorResponse.Error.INTERNAL_ERROR);
    }    
}
```